# Place a DIV side by side with a SPAN, inside another DIV

Tags: html, css

I need to place the `promo` div in the right side of the `alert` div, just like this:

[image]

Please, can some CSS expert help me with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/08rnpxbt/4/

```css
body {
    width:640px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 6px 0 6px;
    padding:18px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p { 
    padding:0;
    margin:8px 0 0 0;
}
div.alert {
    padding:8px 12px 8px 12px;
    margin:20px auto 20px auto;
    text-align:justify;
    border:2px solid #389CF2;
    border-radius:8px;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
    background-image:url(http://i61.tinypic.com/1oxi50.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:8px 11px;
}
div.alert span {
    display:block;
    //float:left;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    margin-left:40px;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:1.3em;
    color:#5C5C5C;
}
div#promo {
    display:block;
    width:80px;
    height:32px;
    padding:4px 2px 2px 2px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:15px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FF0000;
    border:2px dotted #585858;
    border-radius:16px;
    background-color: #FFFFD5;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="alert" style="width:530px; margin:0 auto 10px auto;">
    <span>
        <b>Windows 7 Home Premium - 02 License(s)</b><br>
        Price: U$ 225.00 up to 10X or R$ 210.00 in cash
    </span>
    <div id="promo">15,00% de desconto !</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this CSS rule to your `#promo` element:

```
#promo{
    float: right;
}
```

and change this in your CSS:

```
div.alert span{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you don' set `inline-block` the `#promo` will break in new line like you had it before.

Try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/08rnpxbt/5/)

Comment: Thank you! Simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox attribute for this

just add `display:flex` and `justify-content:space-between`

```
div.alert {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding:8px 12px 8px 12px;
    margin:20px auto 20px auto;
    text-align:justify;
    border:2px solid #389CF2;
    border-radius:8px;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
    background-image:url(http://i61.tinypic.com/1oxi50.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:8px 11px;
}
```